# How navigate without backstack in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Now I'm switching between screens this way

```
navController.navigate(Screen.Overview.route + "/${state.accessToken}")
```

How can I switch to another screen, but still clear the backstack?

Comment: do you want to clear the entire backstack or just pop the last destination from the backstack before navigating to another screen?

Comment: Ideally, it would be useful to know both of these ways.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this function from the [NavController Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Boolean)). By using the `inclusive` parameter and popping the backstack up to the specified topmost destination, you should be able to handle navigation the way you want to.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Answer (score -2):

```
navController.navigate(Screen.Overview.route + "/${state.accessToken}") {
     popUpTo(Screen.Overview.route + "/${state.accessToken}") {
          inclusive = true
     }
}
```

should do the trick